# Newtonsoft JSON: Serializing is generating different output with the same input

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm generating a JSON string from a class input. I don't know why but....It's generating different outputs (different projects), but with the same input (generated classes from Web Service Reference). i.e.:

1st project generates:

```
"{\"authToken\":{\"Token\":\"4f49f29e951d8d4f7e5b1f26aaf924771c9ed5fdfe6a23021d6720f2f5deead7==\",\"UserInfo\":{\"Email\":\"YS00982@mail.com\",\"Locked\":false,\"Phone\":null,\"UserLogin\":\"YS00982\",\"UserName\":\"YS00982 \"}},\"interactionModel\":{\"Description\":\"description\",\"Solicitor\":\"ry13578\",\"Title\":\"title\",\"Urgency\":\"3\"}}"
```

2nd project generates:

```
"{\r\n  \"authToken\": {\r\n    \"token\": \"4f49f29e951d8d4f7e5b1f26aaf924771c9ed5fdfe6a23021d6720f2f5deead7==\",\r\n    \"userInfo\": {\r\n      \"email\": \"YS00982@mail.com\",\r\n      \"locked\": false,\r\n      \"userLogin\": \"YS00982\",\r\n      \"userName\": \"YS00982 \"\r\n    }\r\n  },\r\n  \"interactionModel\": {\r\n    \"description\": \"description\",\r\n    \"solicitor\": \"ry13578\",\r\n    \"title\": \"title\",\r\n    \"urgency\": \"3\"\r\n  }\r\n}"
```

There are two main differences: uppercase in the first character (token vs Token) and also "\r\n" added to my json.

AFAIK I didn't configure anything in the Newtonsoft, so I don't know why does it behave in different way in each project. Does anyone know the reason?

Sample code:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        };
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://ws.domain.com/BackEndService/");
                StringContent c = new StringContent($"{{ \"userLogin\": \"YS00982\", \"password\": \"pass\"}}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage r = await client.PostAsync("service.svc/Authenticate", c);
            string d = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            string token = string.Empty;
            D authres = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<D>(d);

            if (authres.d.success)
            {
                AuthToken authToken = new AuthToken();
                authToken = authres.d.Data;
                var model = new InteractionModel
                {
                    Description = "description",
                    Title = "title",
                    Solicitor = "ry13578",
                    Urgency = "3"
                };

                object obj = new
                {
                    authToken = authToken,
                    interactionModel = model
                };
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, Formatting = Formatting.None, ContractResolver = null });
                Console.WriteLine(json);
                StringContent cc = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                r = await client.PostAsync("CAUMobileService.svc/CreateInteraction", cc);

                d = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                Console.WriteLine(d);
            }
```

Best regards

Comment: I would suggest reducing each project to a [mcve] - once you have two pieces of code you expect to behave equivalently, we'll be in a much better position to explain the differences. It would also help if you'd provide the actual JSON, rather than the debugger-escaped version of the string.

Comment: In both cases I copied the output of the debugger. And also, In both projects I'm using the same piece of code without changes. I was thinking if this is a Newtonsoft configuration.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying *don't* copy it out of the debugger, because we're seeing an escaped version instead of the actual string. And I strongly suspect that while the code you're *looking at* is the same, there's a difference somewhere else... and if you reduce each of the projects to a [mcve] by gradually removing irrelevant parts (and hard-coding data) you'll find that difference. Without seeing any of your code, we've basically got no chance to help you.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet I will add my code of both projects.

Comment: Do you have an actual problem with this? Because they look compatible/interchangeable. And do write  a [mcve] (2x). And elaborate on the platform, version of the Newtonsoft package etc.

Comment: Please only do so *after* you've reduced them to minimal (but still complete) examples.

Comment: In the absence of any demo code, I can only guess that your two projects have different global `JsonSerializerSettings`.  See [How to set custom JsonSerializerSettings for Json.NET in MVC 4 Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13274625) or [JsonSerializerSettings and Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35772387) or (for a console app) [Set default global json serializer settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21815759).

Comment: Yes!!!It looks like the JsonSerializerSettings was configured in other place with this: ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(). But now, how can I avoid that in my particular serialization? BTW, I'm asking that, because the endpoint service is case sensitive.

Comment: @shinjidev - I can't answer that without a [mcve] showing the framework you are using and how you are returning your object currently.  Is it Web API?  MVC Core?  Something else?  You can attach `DefaultNamingStrategy` to your objects as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40687963/3744182) but there might be other methods depending on your framework.

Comment: I have added sample code that generates that problem. In the line of "string json" I'm trying to override the DefaultSettings. Is there any way to do it? Best regards

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be using two separate JsonSerializerSettings instances. The default settings is configured to use camel casing via the ContractResolver:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    };
```

The second instance doesn't specify the ContractResolver:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, Formatting = Formatting.None, ContractResolver = null });
```

The ContractResolver is where the casing will be controlled. The Formatting = Formatting.None will eliminate the newlines in your JSON.

Comment: Yes, I modified that line because I needed to eliminate the newlines. Now, I don't know how to "override" the CamelCasePropertyNameContractResolver.

Comment: Try setting the ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() for Pascal casing.