# How to use C# JsonProperty Serialization

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to return a class object where it will serialize the json without lowercase of the first letter of the property names.   I can add the [JsonProperty{"MyField")] and that does work but is there a easier way as I have a lot of properties to do this for on the class.   I don't want to set a global setting where it may break some things so just trying to see in my API best way to make sure the serialized json returns as is.

Thanks all

Comment: Add `[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(DefaultNamingStrategy))]` to your class.  See: [Issue with serializing data using JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40687963/3744182) and [Configure Json.NET serialization settings on a class level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44805490/3744182).  In fact I think this is a duplicate, agree?

Comment: @dbc awesome that is exactly what I needed thanks.  Should I delete this question do you think?

Comment: You can if you want to.  I marked your question as a duplicate so there's no need to do so.